# How to keep track of all descendant processes to cleanup?

Tags: c, unix, process, operating-system, posix

I have a program that can `fork()` and `exec()` multiple processes in a chain. 
E.g.: process A --> fork, exec B --> fork, exec C --> fork, exec D.  So A is the great-great-grandparent of C.

Now the problem is that I do not have any control of processes B, C and D. So, several things can happen.

1. It might so happen that a descendant process can do `setsid()` to change its process group and session.
2. Or one of the descendant process dies (say C) and hence its child (D) is parented by init.

Therefore, I can't rely on process group id or parent id to track all descendants of A. Is there any reliable way of keeping track of all descendants? More specifically, I would like to kill all the descendants (orphans and otherwise).

It would be also great if its POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [caf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936998/how-to-keep-track-of-all-descendant-processes-to-cleanup/6937475#6937475)'s general sentiment: if a process calls `setsid`, it's saying it wants to live on its own, no matter what . You need to think carefully as to whether you really want to kill them.

That being said, sometimes, you will want some form of “super-session” to contain a tree of processes. There is no tool that provides such super-sessions in the POSIX toolbox, but I'm going to propose a few solutions. Each solution has its own limitations, so it's likely that they won't all be applicable to your case, but hopefully one of them will be suitable.

A clean solution is to run the processes in their own virtualized environment. This could be a FreeBSD-style [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail), Linux [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), or any other kind of virtualization technology. The limitations of this approach are that virtualization technologies are OS-dependant, and the processes will run in a somewhat different context.

If you only have a single instance of these processes on the system and you can get root involved, run the processes as a dedicated user. The super-session is defined as the processes running as the dedicated user. Kill the descendants with `kill(-1, signum)` (note that this will kill the killer process itself unless it's blocked or handled the signal).

You can make the process open a unique file, making sure that the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag is set on the file descriptor. All child processes will then inherit the open file unless they explicitly remove the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag before calling `execve` or close the file. Kill the processes with `fuser -k` or by obtaining the list of process IDs with `fuser` or `lsof` (`fuser` is in POSIX, but not `fuser -k`.) Note that there's a race condition: a process may fork between the time you call `fuser` and the time you kill it; therefore you need to call `fuser` in a loop until no more processes appear (don't loop until all processes are dead, as this could be an infinite loop if one of the processes is blocking your signal).

You can generate a unique random string and define an environment variable with that name, or with a well-known name and that unique string as a value. It will be inherited by all descendant processes unless they choose to change their environment. There is no portable way to search for processes based on their environment, or even to obtain the environment of another process. On many unix variants, you can obtain the information with an option to `ps` (such as `ps -e` on *BSD or `ps e` on Linux); the information may not be easy to parse, but the presence of the unique string is a sufficient indicator. As with `fuser` above, note the need for a loop to avoid a race condition if a descendant calls `fork` too late for you to notice its child but before you could kill the parent.

You can `LD_PRELOAD` a small library that forks a thread that listens on a communication channel, and kills its process when notified. This may disrupt the process if it expects to know about all of its own threads; it's only a possibility on architectures where the standard library is always thread-safe, and you'll miss statically linked processes. The communication channel can be anything that allows the master process to broadcast the suicide order; one possibility is a pipe where each descendant process does a blocking read and the ancestor process closes the pipe to notify the descendants. Pass the file descriptor number through an environment variable.

Comment: thanks @Gilles that was really informative.I like the fuser and environment variable based solutions. I was looking for some kind of process tainting and I think your solutions follow the same thought..

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX way to do this is simply to use process groups.  Descendant processes that explicitly change their process group / session are making a deliberate decision *not* to have their lifetime tracked by their original parent - they are specifically emancipating themselves from the parent's control.  Such processes are not orphans - they are adults that have "flown the nest" and wish to exert control over their own lifetime.

Comment: thanks @caf ...i agree with your sentiment, but i want to kill any rogue processes that got orphaned un-intentionally or otherwise.