# Is it possible to completely manage the life cycle of a process and its forks?

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system

Consider a system that manages user-defined programs:

- A program can be anything. Its command line is defined by non-privileged users in some configuration file. It could be `/bin/ls`, it could be `/usr/sbin/apache`; the user may specify whatever he is permitted to start.
- Each program is run as a non-root user.
- Any given user can configure any number of programs.
- Each program runs for as long as it wants.
- Each program may call `fork()`, `exec()` etc.
- Each program may set itself as a session leader (ie., `setsid()`).
- The system that starts the programs might not run continuously. It starts a program, then quits.
- The action "stop all of program P's processes, including children/forks" must be possible.
- The action "find all processes belonging to program P" must be possible.

Here's the question: How can one provide such a system within the Linux process model?

The naive method:

- Start program with `fork()`, `exec()`, `setuid()`, etc..
- Write the child PID (plus its start timestamp, from `/proc/stat`, to uniquely and permanently identify it) to a file.
- To stop a single process, set `SIGTERM` to PID.
- To find all processes, inspect `/proc` to build the process hiearchy based on the PID.

This method has a big hole: Any process may fork and break out of its process group. It's not sufficient to look at the process hierarchy. After a program has created new processes, it's not possible to trace their origin back to the original program.

A workaround would be to ensure that each program is started with a unique UID. This is not desirable or particularly workable, since a (human) user may define any number of programs; the system would then have to programmatically create new, unique users for each program.

My only idea so far is to inject a special, reserved environment variable into the program's initial process, ie., run the program with `env PROGRAM=myprogram <command line>`. The system could then mandate that all processes must inherit their parent's environment. At regular intervals, the system could trawl `/proc` and forcibly kill any process missing the `PROGRAM` environment variable.

Are there any secrets in the Linux syscall API that I could use?

Comment: Actually I found this, which suggests Linux cgroups, which I think I can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936998/how-to-keep-track-of-all-descendant-processes-to-cleanup

Answer (score 2):

> (1) The action "stop all of program P's processes, including children/forks" must be possible. (2) The action "find all processes belonging to program P" must be possible.

cgroups implement this, and systemd is perhaps the heaviest user to date to make use of (2) to achieve (1). You can break out of progress groups, but not cgroups.